# os.walk() not showing parent folder of a sub folder

Tags: python-3.x

So I was using `os.walk()` and I created a test folder with this structure

```
testFolder
|---folder1
|   |---folder2
|---folder3
```

I tried to list the folders and subfolders using this code

```py
import os
parentPath = "C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\Projects\\testFolder"
for parent, directories, files in os.walk(parentPath, topdown = True):
        for name in directories:
            print("{}".format(os.path.join(parentPath,name)))
```

here is the output of that code

```sh
C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects\testFolder\folder1
C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects\testFolder\folder3
C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects\testFolder\folder2
```

Comment: You are joining the file name to the *root* parent, not the immediate parent. It should be ``os.path.join(parent, name)``. ["To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in ``dirpath``, do ``os.path.join(dirpath, name)``."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize that I have a loop variable. Thanks.